# How to hide certain classes in a widget box?

Tags: javascript, html

So there is a button, which opens up a widgetbox window with multiple fields: a boldColumn containerLabel and a fieldColumn containerField.

```
<tr>
   <td class="boldColumn containerLabel">
       <span class="widgetLabel boldLabel ">Address</span>
   <td class="fieldColumn containerField">
       <-- Contains a field box -->
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="boldColumn containerLabel">
       <span class="widgetLabel boldLabel ">Zip Code</span>
   <td class="fieldColumn containerField">
       <-- Contains a field box -->
</tr>
```

I was wondering, how can I just hide the first row (i.e. the first containerLabel and containerField)?

This is what I've done so far...

```
document.getElementById("nxw_bulkImportDocuments_form").addEventListener("click", testFunc);
    function funcTest() {
          var label = document.getElementsByClassName("boldColumn containerLabel");
          var field = document.getElementsByClassName("fieldColumn containerField");

          label[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
          field[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
     }
```

It's not working for some reason... Any help would be appreciated! THanks!

Comment: Is that code called? put a debugger and check what happens. Your code is correct as far I can tell

Comment: Apparently when I see it in the webapp, it's not implementing the changes

Comment: You are calling testFunc and the function it's named funcTest. I have tested it and it works the way you have implemented it. Just be sure the function name are the same in the declaration and the call. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zxs8ekdp/

Comment: FYI, notice that your html is not a valid one, td tags are not closed properly.

Comment: Because of your invalid HTML you are getting undefined element value by ClassName Please find My Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is not valid

I have made the correction please find

And your function name is also incorrect

**JSField** http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/n4njbmbr/

```js
 function funcTest() {
     var label = document.getElementsByClassName("boldColumn");
     console.log(label.length);
     var field = document.getElementsByClassName("fieldColumn containerField");

          label[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
          field[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
     }
document.getElementById("nxw_bulkImportDocuments_form").addEventListener("click", funcTest);
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
   <td class="boldColumn containerLabel">
       <span class="widgetLabel boldLabel ">Address</span>
    </td>
   <td class="fieldColumn containerField">
       <!-- Contains a field box -->fsfs
       </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="boldColumn containerLabel">
       <span class="widgetLabel boldLabel ">Zip Code</span>
    </td>
   <td class="fieldColumn containerField">
       <!-- Contains a field box -->fsf
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
       
       <button id="nxw_bulkImportDocuments_form">click </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your JavaScript is inside a `document.ready` statement.
This is so that your JavaScript runs after the DOM has been fully loaded.

If you're looking to do this quickly with jQuery, check out [`document.ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

If you're looking to do this in vanilla JavaScript, [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

it can be helpful

```
<tr  class="cond">
   <td class="boldColumn containerLabel">
       <span class="widgetLabel boldLabel ">Address</span>
   <td class="fieldColumn containerField">
       <-- Contains a field box -->
</tr>
<tr class="cond">
   <td class="boldColumn containerLabel">
       <span class="widgetLabel boldLabel ">Zip Code</span>
   <td class="fieldColumn containerField">
       <-- Contains a field box -->
</tr>
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById("nxw_bulkImportDocuments_form").addEventListener("click", testFunc);
    function funcTest() {
          var field = document.getElementsByClassName("cond");
          field[0].style.display = "none";
     }
```